# Standalone FastCGI Process Manager

Tags: process, cgi, nginx, fastcgi, interprocess

Is there such a thing as a smart standalone FastCGI process manager? I have my custom server in C++ which I am willing to connect to Apache/Nginx as a FastCGI application. Apache has mod_fcgid which offers some process management functionality, but Nginx requires something standalone. Is there such a thing in the wild? I'm trying [spawn-fcgi](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/spawn-fcgi) from lighttpd project, but it's just a wrapper, no a real process manager.

Comment: Have you wound anything good so far?

Comment: Unfortunately not really. It turns out one has to do this kind of stuff himself.

Answer (score 1):

you can try fcgid. https://github.com/chenyf/fcgid, it's a C++ fastcgi server

Answer (score 0):

You can try [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/), it's a light weighted standalone process amanager which not only support fastcgi process management. It can help you to monitoring the processes as a deamon, like your process (fcgi processes or other processes) was killed by some reason, supervisor will restart it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still interested about that in the year 2024, you can also try my project which resembles the functionality of the famous `php-fpm` software, but works with everything that supports the FastCGI startup protocol rather than with the PHP scripts only.

https://github.com/vdudouyt/std-fpm

Answer (score -2):

You can try [php-fpm](http://php-fpm.org/). It works great with Nginx.

Comment: Does it work with applications other than PHP? I will check myself though.

Comment: Nope it seems to work with PHP only, so not much use for me :(